# Why is in order to normalise t-distribution the following function is used $t = z*s$, shouldn't it be $t=z*\frac{\sigma}{s}$?

Tags: normal-distribution, standardization, t-distribution

I am trying to answer the following question:

> Suppose there is a new genetically modified species of pine, with an expected fully
> grown height of 14 metres and a standard deviation of one metre. The normalised
> heights, however, follow a $t_5$ distribution. Suppose one such tree grew to a height of X metres. What is the calculation to normalise this height?

I was able to figure out that sine
$$
z=\frac{(x-\mu)}{\sigma\sqrt(n)}
$$

and
$$
t=\frac{(x-\mu)}{s\sqrt(n)}
$$

We can get
$$
t=z*\frac{\sigma}{s}
$$

But then when solving for the solution the lecture showed the opposite function and he multiplies
[z for s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em9B2.png). This baffles me a lot; hence, could someone please help me to answer why is this the case?

Comment: this is a weird calculation and the setup. I think your professor made this problem herself and screwed up. it's contradictory at the least

Comment: Thanks for the input, we are a bit frustrated with the professor too unfortunately. Would this mean that his solution is also janky and frankly incorrect?

Comment: I don't know if his solution is incorrect because it's not clear what he's trying to do. For instance, he says "expected... standard deviation" is 1 which seems to suggest you know $\sigma$, but then he talks about normalized heights but doesn't give $s$. Maybe he meant that $s=1$?

Comment: Sorry, I think my way of putting in the question was a bit unclear and have adjusted it. From the solution what he did was using 5 degree of freedom and the following 
$$
s^2=\frac{v}{v-2}=\frac{5}{5-2}=\frac{5}{3}
$$
And I could understand this but then I could not figure out how he "standardise" that by using $$t=z*s=\frac{x-14}{1}*\sqrt\frac{5}{3}$$ since I think think it should be divided not multiply.

Comment: yes, he's using a standard variance expression for t with 5 d.f.

Comment: I think I have understood what you're saying now but now I'm even more confused about what he's saying. Would you mind telling me based on the given information, regardless of the confusing factor, what would be your approach for the question?

Comment: You don't need $s$, as you know the true value of the standard deviation equals $1$.  Now, a $t_5$ distribution with scale parameter equal to $1$ has a variance equal to $5/3$; if you normalize the tree height, the standard deviation of the normalized variate would equal $1$, so you need to multiply by $\sqrt{5/3}$ to get the standard deviation back to where it should be (equal to $\sqrt{5/3}$, that is) for a $t_5$ variate.  The question is a little unclear because the mechanism that causes the normalized variate to have a $t_5$ distribution isn't described.

Comment: "Now, a t5 distribution ... t5 variate."

In this case, does it mean that the equivalent of the variance of $t_5$ distribution of a standard normal distribution with the variance of 1 is $5/3$? Hence, when we normalise a t-distribution from a standard normal distribution we would need to multiply it by $\sqrt(5/3)$ to take into account this situation? Could you also please tell me what is a scale parameter in this scenario?

Comment: If I understand you correct,ly, yes.   For a Gaussian distribution, the standard deviation is a scale parameter.   The $t$ distribution has one too, but the difference is that when you divide a (centered) Gaussian variate by its scale parameter, the new variable has a standard deviation of $1$, but if you divide a centered $t_{\nu}$ variate by its scale parameter, the new variable has a standard deviation of $\sqrt{\nu / (\nu-2)}$,

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I know why I'm so confused because the concept of scale parameter was not taught during our subject but then the professor decided to use it without much explanation.